# how to write a shell script to run multiple programs

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, terminal

I want to run two programs

`ssh -f mike@c15-0330-02 'cd /home && nohup Rscript L_1.R> L_1_sh.txt '`

AND

`ssh -f mike@c15-0330-03 'cd /home && nohup Rscript L_2.R> L_2_sh.txt '`

I write a shell script as

```
ssh -f mike@c15-0330-02 'cd /home && nohup Rscript L_1.R> L_1_sh.txt ' &
ssh -f mike@c15-0330-03 'cd /home && nohup Rscript L_2.R> L_2_sh.txt ' &
```

But it always shows

```
: command not found:
: command not found:
: command not found:
```

Comment: Did the commands work on there own? i.e. `ssh -f mike@c15-0330-02 'cd /home && nohup Rscript L_1.R> L_1_sh.txt '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your paths on the remote are correct. Most scripts don't live under /home

Comment: Did the questioner forget the `./` before the `Rscript` or was it something else.